# Android: "Unable to instantiate Fragment"

Tags: java, android

Here is my Java code. The problem is whenever I return to my application from foreground, the app crashes giving the error shown in the stack trace below (unable to instantiate framgent).

MainActivity.java

```
 public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

public static final String KEY_CURRENT_OPTION = "currentOption";
public static final String KEY_SELECT_OPTION = "selectOption";
ProgressDialog dialog = null;
View drawerView;
//ImageView updown;
DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
ListView optionsListView;
ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
private int currentOption = -1;
private boolean isRegistered = false;
BookACabFragment bookNowFragment;
BookACabFragment preBookFragment;
BookingsListFragment bookingsListFragment;
AccountFragment accountFragment;
CouponsFragment couponsFragment;
FavouriteAddressFragment favAddressFragment;
private FavDriversFragment favDriversFragment;
private TypedArray navMenuIcons;
public static SmoothProgressBar mGoogleNow;
//LocationReceiver receiver;
private NavDrawerListAdapter adapterrr;
static int saveInstance = 0;
private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;

String[] optionTitles;
SharedPreferences prefs;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //  Log.d(TAG, "before content view");
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //  Log.d(TAG, "after content view");

    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    assert actionBar != null;



    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#ffffff")));
    // actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable;
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#000000'></font>"));
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout_main);
    optionsListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview_options_drawer);
    mGoogleNow = (SmoothProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.google_now);
    drawerView = findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

    optionsListView.setAdapter(new MainDrawerListAdapter(this));

    optionsListView.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

    optionTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.main_drawer_options);

    navMenuIcons = getResources()
            .obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);
    navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(optionTitles[0], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, -1)));
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(optionTitles[1], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1)));
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(optionTitles[2], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(2, -1)));
    // Communities, Will add a counter here
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(optionTitles[3], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(3, -1), true, "22"));
    // Pages
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(optionTitles[4], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(4, -1)));
    // What's hot, We  will add a counter here
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(optionTitles[5], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(5, -1), true, "50+"));
    //   navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(optionTitles[6], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(6, -1), true, "50+"));

    navMenuIcons.recycle();
    adapterrr = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
            navDrawerItems);
    prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    editor = prefs.edit();
    optionsListView.setAdapter(adapterrr);


    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.drawable.navopener, R.string.app_name, R.string.app_name) {
        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);


        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);


        }
    };
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null && extras.containsKey(KEY_CURRENT_OPTION)) {
        currentOption = extras.getInt(KEY_CURRENT_OPTION);
    }

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        currentOption = savedInstanceState.getInt(KEY_CURRENT_OPTION);
    }



    selectDrawerItem(currentOption);


}


@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putInt(KEY_CURRENT_OPTION, currentOption);

    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(drawerView)) {
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(drawerView);
            } else {
                mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(drawerView);
            }
            break;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void GotoTab(int i) {
    if (bookingsListFragment == null)
        bookingsListFragment = BookingsListFragment.newInstance();
    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, BookingsListFragment.newInstance());
    ft.commit();
}



      /* @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //setTitle("REPORT AN ISSUE");
            setTitle("Booking Detail" );

        ActionBar actionbar = getActionBar();
//actionbar.setIcon(R.drawable.icon);
        actionbar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#ff00000")));

        actionbar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        MenuInflater menuinflater = getMenuInflater();
        menuinflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }*/

    private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            selectDrawerItem(position);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(drawerView);
        }
    }

    private void selectDrawerItem(int position) {
        if (position == -1) {
            position = 0;
        }

        setTitle(optionTitles[position]);
        currentOption = position;
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                saveInstance = 1;
                Log.e(TAG, "selecting the map fragment");
                ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, BookACabFragment.newInstance(true));
                ft.commit();

                break;

//            case 1:
//
//            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, BookACabFragment.newInstance(false));
//            ft.commit();
//            break;

            case 1:
                saveInstance = 2;

                if (bookingsListFragment == null)
                    bookingsListFragment = BookingsListFragment.newInstance();
                ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, BookingsListFragment.newInstance());
                ft.commit();
                break;


            case 2:
                saveInstance = 3;

                if (accountFragment == null) {
                    accountFragment = AccountFragment.newInstance();
                }

                ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, accountFragment);
                ft.commit();
                break;

            case 3:
                saveInstance = 4;

                if (favAddressFragment == null) {
                    favAddressFragment = favAddressFragment.newInstance();
                }

                ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, favAddressFragment);
                ft.commit();
                break;
            case 4:
                saveInstance = 5;

                if (couponsFragment == null) {
                    couponsFragment = CouponsFragment.newInstance();
                }

                ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, couponsFragment);
                ft.commit();
                break;
            case 5:
                saveInstance = 6;

                logout();
                break;
        }
    }

    /*
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "In resume "+saveInstance, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        if(saveInstance==0){
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, BookACabFragment.newInstance(true));
            ft.commit();
        }else  if(saveInstance==1){
            Log.e(TAG, "selecting the map fragment");
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, BookACabFragment.newInstance(true));
            ft.commit();
            saveInstance=-1;
        }
        else  if(saveInstance==2){

            if(bookingsListFragment == null)
                bookingsListFragment = BookingsListFragment.newInstance();
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, BookingsListFragment.newInstance());
            ft.commit();
            saveInstance=-1;
        }else  if(saveInstance==3){

            if(accountFragment == null) {
                accountFragment = AccountFragment.newInstance();
            }

            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, accountFragment);
            ft.commit();
            saveInstance=-1;
        }else  if(saveInstance==4){
            if (favAddressFragment == null) {
                favAddressFragment = favAddressFragment.newInstance();
            }

            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, favAddressFragment);
            ft.commit();
            saveInstance=-1;
        }else  if(saveInstance==5){
            if (couponsFragment == null) {
                couponsFragment = CouponsFragment.newInstance();
            }

            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, couponsFragment);
            ft.commit();
            saveInstance=-1;
        }
        else  if(saveInstance==6){
            logout();
            saveInstance=-1;
        }
            }

    /**4444
     * Broadcast receiver for changing the fragment
     */
    class FragmentChangeRequestReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
            if (extras != null && extras.containsKey(KEY_SELECT_OPTION)) {
                selectDrawerItem(extras.getInt(KEY_SELECT_OPTION));
            }
        }
    }


    private void logout() {
        final Token token = IoUtils.getTokenFromPrefs(this);
        if (token != null) {
            String regId = GcmUtils.getRegistrationId(this);
            mGoogleNow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
//            dialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "",
//                    "Loading...", true);
//            dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
            AuthAPI.unregisterGCM(token.token, regId, new AuthAPI.OnGcmRegListener() {
                @Override
                public void onRegistered() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onUnregistered() {
                    AuthAPI.logout(token, new AuthAPI.OnAuthResultListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Token token) {
                            Passenger.invalidate();
                            mGoogleNow.setVisibility(View.GONE);
//                            dialog.dismiss();
                            showLogin();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(Exception e) {

                        }
                    });
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Exception e) {

                }
            });

        }
    }

    private void showLogin() {
        IoUtils.deleteTokenFromPrefs(this);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
        MainActivity.this.finish();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }


}
```

BookACabFragment.java

```
public class BookACabFragment extends Fragment implements
        GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener, GoogleMap.OnMarkerDragListener,
        GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener, ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener,LocationListener,GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,View.OnClickListener {
    String driverLongitude, driverlatitude, text;
    String rotation;
   float rotationF;
    TextView tvdisTime;
    ImageView taxiicon,ivCenterMaker;
    HttpPost httppost;
    StringBuffer buffer;
    HttpResponse httpresponse;
    InputStream content;
    JSONArray daArray = null;
    HttpClient httpclient;
    JSONArray data = null;
    String jsonString;
    // HttpClient httpclient;
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs;

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private static final String TAG = "BookACabFragment";
    private static final float MAP_SCROLL_FACTOR = 3.33f;
    private static final float MAP_SINGLE_MARKER_ZOOM = 14;

    GoogleMap googleMap;
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment;
    SharedPreferences prefs;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

    SlidingUpPanelLayout slidingLayout;
    boolean isPanelExpanded = false;
    boolean isConfirmedFragment = false;

    SessionManager s;
    SessionManager session;
    NonSwipeableViewPager viewPager;
    LinearLayout slidePanel;
    BroadcastReceiver receiver;
    boolean isRegistered = false;


    String[] ss;
    ArrayList<Marker> cabMarkers;
    private ArrayList<Cab> mCabs;

    public boolean showCabPicker;
    LatLng ll;
    TextView handleText;
    String RDD = "0";
    ImageView updown;
    int panelHeight;
    int activityHeight;
    boolean panelFullScreen = false;
    public static boolean openSlidingPanel = false;

    View NavView1,NavView2,NavView3,NavView4;
    LinearLayout NavViewMain;
    BasePickerFragment currentPickerFragment;
    PickSourceFragment pickSourceFragment;
    PickCabTypeFragment pickCabTypeFragment;
    PickCabFragment pickCabFragment;
    PickDestinationFragment pickDestinationFragment;
    PickDestinationFragmentPrebook pickDestinationFragmentPrebook;
    ReviewFragment reviewFragment;
    int currentPagerItem = 0;
    String cabDistance="";
    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    public static String ShopLat;
    public static String ShopPlaceId;
    public static String ShopLong;
    // Stores the current instantiation of the location client in this object
    private LocationClient mLocationClient;
    boolean mUpdatesRequested = false;
    private Geocoder geocoder;
    private List<Address> addresses;
    private LatLng latlngcenter;
    String duration = "";
    String distance = "";
    Cab cAutoassign;
    List<Marker> markerList;
    ArrayList<LatLng> locations;
    int viewCount=0;
    private ScheduledExecutorService scheduler;
    private ScheduledFuture<?> scheduledFuture;
    LinearLayout ll_Rn_Rl;
    Button Rn,RL;
    static  int vps=0;
    public BookACabFragment(){}
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onDisconnected() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        int id = v.getId();
        FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        switch (id) {
            case R.id.bt_Rn:
              //  Toast.makeText(getActivity(),openSlidingPanel+"clickqwal",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                openSlidingPanel=true;
                ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, BookACabFragment.newInstance(true));
                ft.commit();



                /

                break;

            case R.id.bt_RL:
                openSlidingPanel=true;
                ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, BookACabFragment.newInstance(false));
                ft.commit();


                             //  ll_Rn_Rl.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                //Your Operation
                break;
        }

    }

    public enum Fragments {
        SOURCE_PICKER,
        CABTYPE_PICKER,
        CAB_PICKER,
        DESTINATION_PICKER;
    }

    Fragments currentFrag;

    String[] handleTitlesRideNow, handleTitlesPreBook;

    public interface NavigationListener {

        public void goBack();

        public void goForward();

        public void goForwardWithoutDestination();
    }

    public static  BookACabFragment newInstance(boolean showCabPicker) {
        BookACabFragment fragment = new BookACabFragment();

        Bundle args = new Bundle(1);
        args.putBoolean("showCabPicker", showCabPicker);
        fragment.setArguments(args);

        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Bundle args = getArguments();
        showCabPicker = args.getBoolean("showCabPicker");

        prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
        editor = prefs.edit();
        handleTitlesRideNow = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.handle_titles_ride_now);
        handleTitlesPreBook = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.handle_titles_prebook);

        ActionBar actionBar = getActivity().getActionBar();
        assert actionBar != null;
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);

        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);



        currentFrag = Fragments.SOURCE_PICKER;

        pickSourceFragment = PickSourceFragment.newInstance(!showCabPicker);
        pickSourceFragment.setOnAttachListener(new PickSourceFragment.OnAttachListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAttach() {
                initMarker();
            }
        });


        if (showCabPicker)
            pickCabFragment = PickCabFragment.newInstance();
        pickDestinationFragment = PickDestinationFragment.newInstance();
        pickDestinationFragmentPrebook = PickDestinationFragmentPrebook.newInstance();
        pickCabTypeFragment = PickCabTypeFragment.newInstance();
        currentPickerFragment = pickSourceFragment;
        reviewFragment = ReviewFragment.newInstance();

        //  initReceivers();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ActionBar actionBar = getActivity().getActionBar();
        assert actionBar != null;
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#ffffff")));
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setIcon(android.R.color.transparent);


        String fontPath = "fonts/RobotoCondensed-Regular.ttf";
        Typeface font2 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), fontPath);
        SpannableStringBuilder SS = new SpannableStringBuilder("                     Book Taxi");
        SS.setSpan (new CustomTypefaceSpan("", font2), 0, SS.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
        actionBar.setTitle(SS);
        int ActionBarTitleID = Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("action_bar_title", "id", "android");
        TextView yourTextView = (TextView)getActivity().findViewById(ActionBarTitleID);
        yourTextView.setTextAppearance(getActivity(), android.R.style.TextAppearance_Large);




        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bookacab, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
      vps=  viewPager.getCurrentItem();
             viewPager.setCurrentItem(vps);
        startTimeScheduledExecutorService();
    }
```

here is the Stack Strace

```
   6428-6428com.cabbooking.passenger EAndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION main
    java.lang.RuntimeException Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.cabbooking.passengercom.cabbooking.passengerapp.screens.MainActivity} android.support.v4.app.Fragment$InstantiationException Unable to instantiate fragment com.cabbooking.passengerapp.screens.BookACabFragment$18 make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java2355)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java2391)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java1335)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java155)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java5520)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java1029)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java796)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by android.support.v4.app.Fragment$InstantiationException Unable to instantiate fragment com.cabbooking.passengerapp.screens.BookACabFragment$18 make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java415)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentState.instantiate(Fragment.java99)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.restoreAllState(FragmentManager.java1807)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java1493)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java908)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java1121)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java1103)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchCreate(FragmentManager.java1896)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate(FragmentActivity.java216)
            at com.cabbooking.passengerapp.screens.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java75)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java5066)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java1101)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java2311)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java2391)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java1335)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java155)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java5520)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java1029)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java796)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by java.lang.InstantiationException can't instantiate class com.cabbooking.passengerapp.screens.BookACabFragment$18; no empty constructor
            at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java1319)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java404)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentState.instantiate(Fragment.java99)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.restoreAllState(FragmentManager.java1807)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java1493)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java908)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java1121)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java1103)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchCreate(FragmentManager.java1896)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate(FragmentActivity.java216)
            at com.cabbooking.passengerapp.screens.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java75)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java5066)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java1101)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java2391)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java1335)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java155)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java5520)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java511)
```

Comment: Your fragments haven't default constructor

Comment: hey i added the empty constructor too..

Comment: public  BookACabFragment () { 
}

Comment: but didnt worked for me :(

Comment: Is Stack Strace same?

Comment: yess.. the same stack trace

Comment: **make sure all of your fragments have a parameterless (empty) constructor**

Comment: checked!! same problem shows up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the log carefully:

```
     Caused by java.lang.InstantiationException can't instantiate class com.cabbooking.passengerapp.screens.BookACabFragment$18; no empty constructor
```

The android os could not instantiate the class **BookACabFragment$18**, not your Fragment **BookACabFragment**!

I do not think that it is possible to create an anonymous fragment, because of the lack of public accessability.

Update: After reading your code. I think I found your the wrong code:

```
mapFragment = new SupportMapFragment() {
                @Override
                public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
                    googleMap = mapFragment.getMap();
                    if (googleMap != null) {
                        googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(true);
                        googleMap.setOnMapClickListener(BookACabFragment.this);
                        googleMap.setOnMarkerDragListener(BookACabFragment.this);
                        googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(BookACabFragment.this);
                        //googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

                        pickedLocation = GeoUtils.getLocationFromPreferences(getActivity());
                    }
                }

            };
```

You cannot create an anonymous fragment. Either put your Fragment to a new class or create it as static-class in your BookACabFragment. I would prefer the first option:

```
public class MySupportMapFragment extends SupportMapFragment {
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        // Your funky stuff
    }
}
```

Additional hint: Your class has over 2000 lines of code. You should really refactor this monolith.

Comment: hey ... i tried by giving the  public access but didn't work out :(

Comment: @Androidiseverythingforme could you show the corresponding code?

Comment: I mean BookACabFragment$18 code especially. It will be included in BookACabFragment.java

Comment: ok after making the separate class MySupportmapFramgent..how i supposed to call it in setUpMap() method ..

Comment: getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(containerviewId, new MySupportMapFragment()).commit(); @see: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentManager.html

Comment: can you please give me the hint how to do tht in a separate class ... ??

Comment: this is wht i have dono so far in MySupportMapFragment.java see : http://pastebin.com/c7bwqBGm

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an empty constructor to your `BookACabFragment`.

```
public BookACabFragment() { 
}
```

Comment: empty constructor for BookACabFragment or BookingsListFragment ??

Comment: @Androidiseverythingforme I didn't look carefully. It should be `BookACabFragment` according to your logs.

Comment: yes ..but i added the empty constructor too..but tht didnt worked